# I cannot reliably access the shared domain directory on my Server 2012R2 domain controllers

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two Virtual Domain Controllers, each one hosted on a separate physical server, in my domain. A few weeks ago, everything seemed to be all well. Recently, however, I have noticed that when I try to access the domain's shared volume (i.e. \mydomain.com), I get an error box that says "The specified network name is no longer available".

This seems to be the case on both of my domain controllers, and carries the side-effect of my group policy settings within the GPEDIT console not successfully loading. I can get a list of all the objects themselves, but clicking the objects results in each claiming there are no settings for either Computer or User, even on ones that definitely had settings.

Now, if I reboot the domain controllers, this seems to resolve it for a time. I am able to load up my policy object settings, and I am able to get to that domain directory without any fuss. If I let it sit a while, though, it goes right back to where it was before (timing is not determined, but I let it sit over the last weekend after making changes on Thursday and it was back to misbehaving on Tuesday).

Interesting that if, when I detect this breakage, I have the GPEDIT console up it doesn't stop rendering settings suddenly. If I close the console and try to re-open it, I sometimes get the error message box that says the "Stub received bad data" and the console fails to load. If I try to run it again, the console loads but wont grab the policy settings.

I don't seem to have replication issues in general, so I don't think it's anything that is going to break my domain. Indeed, it seems (though isn't quite confirmed) that computers in the domain get policy without issue even when it is "broken".

I suspect this has something to do with STIG-related settings I have been tasked to deploy on a variety of things in the domain. For Server 2012 and domain controller objects, this was set a few weeks ago, so the timing seems like it lines up. I can comb through the settings I deployed on the DC and try to work it out myself (and indeed, I will have to do that) but I believe it worthwhile to inquire here because even if I do find out what policy setting (if any) broke my domain volume access, I will need to have an understanding of why so I can work around it - I figure the learned minds here might have some experiences.

Google searching for this error seems to turn up a lot of leads, but none of the situations are quite the same, and a handful of remedial actions suggested that seem like they might apply have not yielded results.

Has anyone had a similar experience, and if so how did you resolve it?

Comment: You need to perform a packet capture when the symptom occurs.

Comment: Hi, do you mean accessing a namespace or the sysvol share ? \\mydomain.com or \\dc\ ?

Comment: Yagmoth555, you are correct - something happens and breaks my access to \\\mydomain.com.  For example it was A-OK this morning around 9AM, but I tried it just now and it failed - but it failed a little differently in that it prompted for my domain admin's credentials (which I keyed in correctly but it returned this error: (part 1)

Comment: part 2:  \\mydomain.com is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this network resource.  Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in.  For example:  blank passwords aren't allowed, sigin-times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.

Comment: part 3:  However, this account is the Domain Admin, and is in the proper group.  I ran into this issue a while back trying to add a new workstation, but I reset the password on the account in question and it worked fine.  Interestingly, I tried going to \\mydomain.com again after I closed that error box and the list of domain shares came right up (sysvol, etc) but closing and trying again just brings back the error about blank passwords (it's not blank!).

Comment: You might be resolving to the two different DCs for the domain, and one might be having problems while the other doesn't. How's your replication? DFS(R) , not just AD/DNS replication

Comment: Mfinni, apparently it is not good.Looking at the log in Srv Manager on "VDC02" I see yesterday and today there are some warnings and errors related to DFSR and partmgr.Same on my "VDC01", though not all errors are the same.The log only goes back to 9/9,which is odd since I was having errors before then I think.Some of these errors are close enough in time stamp that they're probably interrelated.I have not dealt with DFS much directly so I will need to delve into this and see if that solves the original issue.

Comment: As a general follow-up, I suspect this *might* have something to do with my Domain Admin account.  I've been rolling out reconfigurations required from above,and it might have generated a conflict.What I noticed today was that typically if the \\domain thing fails and I get a prompt for credentials, it denies my credentials with an error message.I made myself a test domain admin account and tried providing its credentials - success.  Not quite solved the main issue so the hunt continues when I have some time...